# How to order sql query by other table values

Tags: mysql, sql

i know that stackoverflow is remember answer for this question, but I have a bit different situation. 
I have a lot cells in second table, but SQL query get only first. Ok, not all query, only WHERE tag.

Ex: 
**1 table**:

```
user_id = 1
user_id = 2
```

**2 table**:

```
user_id = 1 | year = 2015 | rating = 55
user_id = 1 | year = 2016 | rating = 10
user_id = 2 | year = 2016 | rating = 50
user_id = 2 | year = 2016 | rating = 5
```

**SQL query:**

```
$query = "SELECT c.*,v.upvotes
        FROM ".PREFIX."_users c
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id,pol,vid_sporta,year_sport,category,SUM(rating) as upvotes
        FROM ".PREFIX."_userrating
        GROUP BY user_id
        ) v
        ON c.user_id = v.user_id
        WHERE year_sport='2015'
        ORDER BY upvotes DESC";
```

*This query give me only one user, whitch has **2015 first**.*

I need some while cycle in SQL query :)
Help, please :)

Comment: Depending on where the `pol,vid_sporta,year_sport,category` fields are located, selecting them without grouping on them can be a recipe for disaster. ...and it only has 1 record, because only one satisfies your WHERE condition.....because of the group by ;)

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: Thanks :) But I need only one show one user with rating by this user.

Comment: @P.Salmon I'm shocked you can't answer this question without knowing what is expected.

Comment: @Matt I need full user's rating by params. http://rgho.st/8DrFqpwfy this screenshot from my PREFIX_userrating table. <br> If I remove `GROUP BY user_id` I get right data from database, but one user show a lot times (How much cells in DB - so many shows). How to fix it right? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that there maybe a couple of issues going on.

First,

```
SELECT user_id,pol,vid_sporta,year_sport,category,SUM(rating) as upvotes
```

SHOULD BE

```
SELECT user_id,SUM(rating) as upvotes
```

You only want to include the columns that you are returning to the rest of your query and any column that is not apart of an aggregate function must also appear in your `GROUP BY` statement.

Second and this is why you may only be getting 1 record is the location of your `WHERE year_sport = '2015'`.  Because the where condition is in the outer query it is treating your `LEFT JOIN` as an `INNER JOIN` and limiting to all results that have that `year_sport` in `userrating`.  Move the where statement to your inner query and you should get all of your users but only `upvotes` from `year_sport =2015`.

```
$query = "SELECT c.*,v.upvotes
        FROM ".PREFIX."_users c
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT user_id,SUM(rating) as upvotes
        FROM ".PREFIX."_userrating
       WHERE year_sport='2015'
        GROUP BY user_id
        ) v
        ON c.user_id = v.user_id
        ORDER BY upvotes DESC";
```

Comment: Just a note if you know you only have 1 rating for year_sport='2015' per user then you don't need and aggregate function or group by.  It is safer the way it is now in case you included multiple years or there are duplicate records...but you could change "SUM(rating) AS upvotes" to "rating as upvotes" and remove the group by clause as you tried